# Push PostGIS DB to OpenShift PostGIS DB

Tags: postgresql, openshift, postgis

I followed this [tutorial on the Open shift site](https://blog.openshift.com/build-your-own-google-maps-and-more-with-geoserver-on-openshift/).  I am now trying to add my own data and am not having any luck.  I have a postGIS DB managed by PGAdmin III on my local machine.  How do I get it to the cloud?

Answer (score 2):

I would use port forwarding to connect to the database on OpenShift and import the data to the database. At a high level, the steps would be:

1. Dump the data from your local database
2. Start port forwarding using `rhc port-forward` command.
3. Connect to the remote OpenShift database from your local machine and import the data

You might want to read [this blog post](https://blog.openshift.com/set-up-local-access-to-openshift-hosted-services-with-port-forwarding/) about OpenShift port forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was downgrade to ruby version 1.9.3. Port forwarding worked without an issue after that